# Linked list and pointer to incomplete class type

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to compare a letter to data part in order to insert it in alphabetical order in linked list, What is wrong with this?

```
typedef struct{
    char data;
    struct list_node *next;
}list_node;

typedef struct{
    list_node *head;
}list;
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
void input_char(list *my_list, char x)
{
    list_node *node = (list_node*)calloc(1, sizeof(list_node));
    list_node *tmp = my_list->head;
    node->data = x;

    if (tmp == NULL)
        my_list->head = tmp;
    else if (tmp->next == NULL)
    {
        if (x < tmp->data)
        {
            node->next = tmp;
            my_list->head = node;
        }
        else
            tmp->next = node;

        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    else
    {
        if (x < tmp->next->data) 
  // This following line says "Error, Pointer to incomplete type is not allowed.
        {
            node->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next = node;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: C does not support classes. If you compile as C++, change the tag. See [ask]. What error message do you get? Where?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ: In C++ a `struct` is a class type. Did you read the title ( "Linked list and pointer to incomplete **class** type")?

Comment: A type. alias (as introduced with the `typedef` keyword) is not the same as a structure tag (the name of a structure). So doing like `struct some_typedef_name *foobar` will not ever work, unless the structure tag has the same name as the type alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
typedef struct{
    char data;
    struct list_node *next;
}list_node;
```

to

```
typedef struct list_node{
    char data;
    struct list_node *next;
}list_node;
```

Your compiler doesn't know what `struct list_node` is, so you have to declared it.

Comment: It fixed the issue, Thanks you. I will accept it as an answer as soon as possible.